# When playing as Woodie, is there any way to get the Glommer Flower?

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

In Don't Starve (Reign of Giants), on nights with a full moon, I can pick the Glommer Flower at the Glommer Statue, and thereafter the Glommer follows me around, providing a sanity boost if I stand close to him.

The trouble is, when playing as Woodie, I turn into a Werebeaver at the full moon.  When my log meter drains and I transform back, I pass out until the next morning.

Given this, is there any way, as Woodie, to somehow obtain the Glommer Flower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken form [Woodie's wiki page](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Woodie):

> Due to his curse the only way currently to get an Old Bell with Woodie in the Reign of Giants DLC , without the Console, is to plant a Fleshy Bulb near Glommer's Statue, let the Eyeplants take Glommer's Flower off the statue and kill the Lureplant before it digests it.

Comment: Nice!  I'll have to give that a try.